# remove repetition when switching enum class

Tags: c++11, enums

When I switch on an `enum class` I have to restate the `enum class` in every case. This bugs me since outside of `constexpr`-constructs it is hard to imagine what else I could mean. Is there away to inform the compiler that everything inside a block should be resolved to an `enum class` of my choice if there is a match?

consider the following example that contains a compiling snippet and for comparisson a non compiling snippet (commented out) that I would like to write.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class State : std::uint8_t;
void writeline(const char * msg);
void Compiles(State some);

enum class State : std::uint8_t
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 1
};

int main()
{
    Compiles(State::zero);
    return 0;
}

void Compiles(State some)
{
    switch (some)
    {
    case State::zero: //State::
        writeline("0");
        break;
    case State::one: //State::
        writeline("1");
        break;
    default:
        writeline("d");
        break;
    }
}


//void WhatIWant(State some)
//{
//  using State{ //this makes no sense to the compiler but it expresses what I want to write
//      switch (some)
//      {
//      case zero: //I want the compiler to figure out State::zero
//          writeline("0");
//          break;
//      case one: //I want the compiler to figure out State::one
//          writeline("1");
//          break;
//      default:
//          writeline("d");
//          break;
//      }
//  }
//}

void writeline(const char * msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to use a switch statement and have the compiler figure out the `enum class`, maybe after giving a hint once?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, unless you use an old style (non-class) enum. One of the advantages of enum classes is that you avoid naming conflicts by using fully qualified names for every enum value.

Comment: Someone actually wrote a proposal about this recently. It was rejected.

Comment: @T.C. where can I find that proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum class` spessially designed in a way so you **have to** apply `State::` every time.

If you don't want to use `State::` prefix in every statement, just use old-style enum from c++98.

NOTE: with C++11 you still can use smth like: `enum MyEnym`**`: std::uint8_t`**`{ ... }` with regular enums.